# When is the "best" time to get a gunite pool installed?

Tags: installation, pool

Is there a time of the year where pool installers are generally "cheaper", due to lack of business?

I've heard that it's best to purchase decks in the fall, since that is the slow season. Just not sure the same applies to pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are from VA. If you're in an area that doesn't get frost into the ground, then it would be safe to install a pool at any time during the year. Just guessing here, but I would imagine that pool companies would be begging for business shortly after the pool closing season, late fall, early winter, or before the ground freezes and snow falls. Definitely that way here in the north country.  Again, really just a guess, got no evidence for ya. Maybe one of our contributors from your area may have some better advise.

Answer (score 1):

Any time between Labor Day, when it usually starts cooling off nationwide, and Memorial Day, the first real summer holiday for many people, the pool guys are mostly twiddling their thumbs. There's a little work to be had in the fall, when a problem discovered by a homeowner during the summer is nipped in the bud before it's forgotten, but new installations are normally done in the spring and early summer. During the end of the summer season and just after, pool guys will do quite a bit to keep their seasonal staff on the payroll, before laying them off and hunkering down for the winter. In a few areas, pool digging can be done in winter, but you might actually pay a premium to have guys working outdoors in even a Southern winter averaging 40*.